# Валидация RadioButton'ов в WPF на основе IDataErrorInfo

Tags: c#, wpf, валидация

Задача: создать аккуратную систему валидации контролов в Window WPF, причем на основе их взаимосвязи. Например, если стоит RadioButton "пол - женский" - то валидируем группу TextBox'ов по их значению, а если не стоит - не валидируем. Просто отключать группу TextBox'ов нельзя по бизнес-логике. Пользователь должен иметь возможность вводить любые данные в любой момент, но нужно красить красным то, что вводить не нужно, а не запрещать вводить.

Создал во VM блок валидации на основе IDataErrorInfo:

```
    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            string error = String.Empty;
            switch (columnName)
            {
                case "RelationOther":
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(RelationOther) && !RelationTypeMap[10])
                        error = "Ошибка! Указание описания не требуется"; break;
                case "Position":
                    //Обработка ошибок для свойства Position
                    break;
            }
            return error;
        }
    }
    public string Error
    {
        get { return string.Empty; }
    }
```

где RelationTypeMap[10] - это элемент, соответствующий варианту "не родственник" в массиве, на который привязан набор из 11 RadioButton'ов. Смысл: валидировать RelationOther только есть отмечен пункт иной пункт, кроме "не родственник", в противном случае - не валидировать и молча принимать введенную строку.

Вот разметка:

```
<TextBox Name="RelationOther" Style="{StaticResource TextBox}" 
    Text="{Binding RelationOther, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

<RadioButton Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3"  GroupName="q1" Style="{StaticResource LeftChecker}" IsChecked="{Binding RelationTypeMap[10], Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <RadioButton.Content>
        <TextBlock Text="не род-&#10;ственник" Style="{StaticResource CheckerText}"/>
    </RadioButton.Content>
</RadioButton>
```

Проблема: если RadioButton уже стоит в позиции, кроме "не родственник" - все валидируется. Если уже стоит в позиции "не родственник" - не валидируется, как и нужно. Однако, если написать текст, и сменить галочку - то событие валидации не срабатывает. Смена галочки вообще не вызывает это событие, отладчик даже не попадает в индексатор public string this[string columnName].

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне заставить VM запускать валидацию текстового поля, если меняется связанные с ним логически RadioButton'ы?

Comment: Я имею ввиду, что изменение значения TextBox'а вызывает срабатывание события, и в обработчике (в индексаторе) я могу проверить состояние RadioButton'ов. А изменение RaioButton'ов - не вызывает срабатывание валидации, несмотря на соответствующие инструкции в binding'e RadioButton'а, я не попадаю в индексатор, и обработать заполненность TextBox'а не могу. Ставить кучу костылей на Set'тер каждой галочки я, мягко говоря, не хочу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, можно сделать `Boolean` свойства для каждой `Radiobutton` и общее итоговое свойство, значение которого изменяется в зависимости от выбранной радиокнопки, вот такая вьюмодель

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo
{
    //ctor
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        AnimalType = "NotAnimal";
    }


    public bool NotAnimalSelected
    {
        get => AnimalType.Equals("NotAnimal");
        set => AnimalType = "NotAnimal";
    }

    public bool CowSelected
    {
        get => AnimalType.Equals("Cow");
        set => AnimalType = "Cow";
    }

    public bool DogSelected
    {
        get => AnimalType.Equals("Dog");
        set => AnimalType = "Dog";
    }

    public bool CatSelected
    {
        get => AnimalType.Equals("Cat");
        set => AnimalType = "Cat";
    }

    private string _AnimalType;
    public string AnimalType
    {
        get => _AnimalType;
        set
        {
            _AnimalType = value;

            OnPropertyChanged("NotAnimalSelected");
            OnPropertyChanged("CowSelected");
            OnPropertyChanged("DogSelected");
            OnPropertyChanged("CatSelected");
            //!!!Вот здесь, еще оповещаем об изменении в Name
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }


    private string _Name;
    public string Name
    {
        get => _Name;
        set
        {
            _Name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    //IDEI
    public string Error => String.Empty;
    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            //В случае если выбрано не животное, то проверки нет
            if (NotAnimalSelected) return String.Empty;

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Name) || Name.Trim().Length <= 3)
            {
                return "Кличка не может быть короче 4-х символов";
            }
            return String.Empty;
        }
    }


    //INPC
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Такая разметка вьюшки

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0"
                Margin="20">
        <RadioButton Content="Не животное"
                     GroupName="Animal"
                     IsChecked="{Binding NotAnimalSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"></RadioButton>
        <RadioButton Content="Корова"
                     GroupName="Animal"
                     IsChecked="{Binding CowSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"></RadioButton>
        <RadioButton Content="Собака"
                     GroupName="Animal"
                     IsChecked="{Binding DogSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"></RadioButton>
        <RadioButton Content="Кошка"
                     GroupName="Animal"
                     IsChecked="{Binding CatSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"></RadioButton>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
        <TextBlock Text="Кличка"
                   Margin="100,0,0,0" />
        <TextBox Width="200"
                 Height="23"
                 Text="{Binding Name, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,
                                UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Пример работы
[image: пример работы]

P.S. После уточняющего комментария был добавлен в свойство AnimalType вызов `OnPropertyChanged("Name");` что заставляет сработать проверку введенных данных в это поле.

Comment: К сожалению, у вас тоже самое, что и у меня. На вашем же примере, мне нужно добиться такого эффекта: ставим галку "не животное", пишем кличку из двух букв - не валидируется - меняем галку на "кошка" - и кличка тут же сама окрашивается красным (срабатывает валидация на ней, хотя мы меняли не TextBox, а RadioButton). Именно сразу при изменении галки, а не когда мы снова вернемся в это поле и изменим хотя бы один символ. Но вы точно уловили суть моей задачи. Спасибо.

Comment: @АндрейКутасевич ловите исправление.